# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: error:10000438:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:TLSV1_ALERT_INTERNAL_ERROR

Tags: ssl, apache-pulsar

I'm unable to connect to my Pulsar test cluster from my local environment, but it was working fine yesterday. Nothing has changed on the client-side or server-side. When I try to connect from my app, I get this exception:

```
2021-08-24T17:07:55,776 [pulsar-io-23-15] WARN  org.apache.pulsar.broker.service.ServerCnx - [/10.16.13.41:23586] Got exception io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: error:10000438:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:TLSV1_ALERT_INTERNAL_ERROR
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:468)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:792)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:475)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:378)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: error:10000438:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:TLSV1_ALERT_INTERNAL_ERROR
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.shutdownWithError(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1007)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.sslReadErrorResult(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1271)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.unwrap(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1225)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.unwrap(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1296)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.unwrap(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1339)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$SslEngineType$1.unwrap(SslHandler.java:205)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1340)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeNonJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1247)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1284)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:498)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:437)
    ... 15 more
```

Restarting the app does not resolve the issue.
We're using Pulsar token-auth with a pretty vanilla configuration:

```java
     client = PulsarClient.builder().serviceUrl(serviceUrl)
           .tlsTrustCertsFilePath(serverCertificateFilePath.toString())
           .enableTlsHostnameVerification(false)
           .allowTlsInsecureConnection(false)
           .authentication(AuthenticationFactory.token(authToken))
           .build();
```

The consumer is also pretty standard (though it has a DLQ) and looks like this:

```java
    pulsarClient.newConsumer(Schema.STRING)
                .consumerName(String.format("%s:%s", consumerProperties.getSubscriptionName(), UUID.randomUUID()))
                .topic(consumerProperties.getDeadLetterTopic())
                .subscriptionName(consumerProperties.getSubscriptionName())
                .subscriptionType(SubscriptionType.Shared)
                .messageListener(deadLetterTopicMessageListener)
                .ackTimeout(consumerProperties.getAcknowledgeTimeout(), TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .subscribe();
```

We've double-checked that the token and certificates are all correct.

Also, the broker `tlsProtocol` includes v1, as follows:

```
    tlsProtocols=TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

We've seen some edge cases where client VPN issues result in this error message.
Some users have reported that this issue is resolved after restarting, clearing their docker cache, and re-connecting to the VPN.
One user reported that it went away after multiple restarts, so it's possible that something times out eventually.